# Is there auto updater/patcher you can implement for you java/scala app?

Tags: java, implementation, auto-update, patch

I'm making a game which I'm planning to update a lot. The previous game I made, I just let users download whole game or patches every time a new version is released but I want to implement online auto-patch feature if it isn't too much trouble to implement. An auto patcher like many applications and online games use.

I do not really want to make it from scratch, and I don't want to spend much time building the patching system if it is too much bother, maybe about a week at most.

Is there any easy-to-implement auto patcher library or software or plug-in you can use for java/scala application?

My game is written in scala, and it is an ordinary offline game. users need to receive either whole game folder in a zip or files that have been changed in a zip, then extracted and copied to the game folder. The game only runs on windows and no plan to port to android/iOS. At least, I don't plan to use auto patcher for other platform.

Thanks.

Comment: *"The game only runs on windows"* Does it not work on Mac. OS X and *nix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never tried that but maybe a Scala app can be used with WebStart. Once you changed the jar on your server your users are asked to download an update when they start the app the next time. These updates can be obligatory or optional.

Comment: See also the [info. page on Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).